# Relationship between the first zeroes of Bessel functions.

Tags: roots, special-functions, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

Letting $J_\nu$ denote the Bessel function of order $\nu$, if $0 < a < b$ will the first zero of $J_{0}$ be less than the first zero of $J_a$ be less than the first zero of $J_b$? Does this hold for the $k$th zero in general?

I am solving the radial Schrodinger equation
with potential $\exp(-r/a)$ and encountered a quantization condition involving the zeroes of the Bessel function. I have looked over some tables for the zeroes of Bessel functions and see that they generally follow that pattern, so I am curious if there is a way to prove/disprove that statement, especially for non-integer $\nu$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Have a look at Theorem 1.3 of _Interlacing of positive real zeros of Bessel functions_, Palmai and Apagyi, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0976.pdf. It's claimed $j_{\nu, s} < j_{\nu+\varepsilon, s}$ for $0 < \varepsilon \leq 1$.

Comment: I guess I ought to have looked more closely at the proof in the paper, the part where it states that that particular inequality is demonstrated in Watson's _A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions_. Credit where it's due.